# JQuery Autocomplete for dom elements that are disabled/enabled

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, autocomplete

I have a page with multiple text fields that I wanted to have the JQuery autocomplete functionality.

course.html.erb

```
<textarea class="text_area courses" id="dynamic_id" name="dynamic_name"></textarea>
```

more_courses.js.erb

```
<textarea class="text_area courses" id="dynamic_id" name="dynamic_name" disabled></textarea>
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery-ui
```

courses.js

```
$(".courses").autocomplete({
    source: '/courses'
  })
```

The problem I am having is some of the text fields are coming from a js.erb file after a tick. It injects another text area with a search course filed via a js.erb.

The second text area's autocomplete does not work.

How do I make second text area visible for autocomplete?

Comment: This is a jQuery UI feature, you may want to add `jquery-ui` tag. You may need to run `refresh` or `enable` after the checkbox is changed. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following fixed the issue

courses.js

```
 $(function(){
  $(document).on("keydown.autocomplete",".courses",function(e){
    $(this).autocomplete({
      source : '/courses'
    });
  });
});
```